# Opening a file in Assembly Language independent of OS

Tags: assembly, file-io, operating-system, x86, osdev

I have been trying to figure out how to open a file from the hard drive in assembly. I want to do this without using DOS interrupts or anything that would require an operating system, because I am trying to build a simple OS. I am fine with BIOS interrupts, of course.

Comment: What file? A file is an O/S abstraction. In case of a disk file, you'll have to use whatever disk read/write capabilities your particular BIOS supports.

Comment: ...or bypass the BIOS and talk directly to the hardware.

Comment: how would you talk directly to a hard drive? I am aware of the in and out instructions, but I don't know anything about using it with the hard drive.

Comment: You use ATA to talk with the drive. Lots of information is available [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA), covering all forms. You are probably most interested in [PIO mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode), which is the default. That page also describes the most commonly used port numbers for `in` and `out`. (You should check PCI to find the actual ports, but these values will work for testing or if you have no PCI.)

Comment: @kjmcgrinder: Some code that may help you; [mindrvr](https://github.com/unnali/akari/blob/master/src/packages/ata/mindrvr.cpp) for speaking ATA (PIO and DMA), and a [driver for mindrvr](https://github.com/unnali/akari/blob/master/src/packages/ata/main.cpp). This is all in C++, but you get the idea. Here's [some code which uses PCI to discover the real ports](https://github.com/unnali/akari/blob/master/src/packages/piix3/main.cpp), and here's [some code to do the PCI bits](https://github.com/unnali/akari/blob/master/src/packages/pci/main.cpp). It's all tied up in the OS, but may it help you.

Comment: You can read without even using BIOS. You "browse" through PCIe configuration space to find SATA controller, initialize it, create required structures and program it to read sectors. Then interpret this in context of a selected file system.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: that is very helpful, and looks like a good website too.

Comment: oh, one more thing. I think I figured out how to open files now, but how can I send the opened files instructions to the cpu for excecution?

Comment: Without OS specification you won't know what file system is being used anyway... so you'll have to implement a load of read instructions for every different file system you can imagine. Seems kinda like reinventing the wheel. That's what OSes are _for_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OS provides two sets of capabilities that you have to emulate to access files:

- A device driver, that can read and write raw data (in your case, to/from the disk)
- A library of facilities that understands the structure of the file and abstractly
  how to read the parts; this calls the driver to do that actual I/O.

You might be able to invoke BIOS calls to simulate a bad device driver; normally real drivers are complex to ensure efficiency and good error recovery, which the BIOS routines simply don't do.

But what you'll find hard to do on you own is to emulate the "file access" library.  Modern file systems store files on a disk in fairly complicated ways to minimize access times while allowing files to spread across most of the disk.

If you insist on doing this, you better read up on the file system structures for whatever filesystem (Linux? Windows?) you intend to access.  Be prepared to discover those documents are incomplete and out of date with respect to the real OS.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://alexfru.narod.ru/os/fat/fat.html) how you can access FAT12/16/32 using only the BIOS. `_boot\BOOT12.ASM` and `_boot\BOOT16.ASM` are FAT12 and FAT16 bootsectors respectively that can load and run from the root of the booted disk a standard .COM or .EXE program named `STARTUP.BIN`. These bootsectors are written for NASM. There's also C reference code for FAT12/16/32 file I/O in `stdio\FAT.c`.